# UI elements not appearing with variables coming from segue

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, segue, ckrecord

Controller One which holds a CK Record, "Detail". One button in Controller One segues to another Controller. I have the following segue set up for that logic...

```
@IBAction func booton(_ sender: Any) {
    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "lastsegue"
        {
          if let destination = segue.destination as? FoodDetail01
          {
            let lastreservation = detail.value(forKey: "Reservation") as? String
            let lasttake = detail.value(forKey: "Take") as? String

            destination.reservation = lastreservation
            destination.take = lasttake
        }...
```

In Controller Two, I have the following receiving variables and the labels set to these new variables.

```
import UIKit

class FoodDetail01: UIViewController {

     var reservation: String!
     var take: String!

@IBOutlet weak var reservationlabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var takelabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.reservationlabel.text = reservation
    self.takelabel.text = take
}
```

However, which is causing me problems, when I run this code, no labels (hooked up correctly) appear in Controller Two. As seen in the picture.

[Missing Labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5KCI.png)

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Up-voted @Nirav-D answer. It's correct. FIRST - you should **never** ended a function within a function (like you have). Second (and less emphasized) Nowadays, Swift uses Dictionary unless there's a specific reason for NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write prepareForSegue as a separatefunction and call performSegue to invoke segue

Please find the code in SWIFT 3

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "lastsegue"
    {
      if let destination = segue.destination as? FoodDetail01
      {
        let lastreservation = detail.value(forKey: "Reservation") as? String
        let lasttake = detail.value(forKey: "Take") as? String

        destination.reservation = lastreservation
        destination.take = lasttake
      }
    }
}

@IBAction func booton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "lastsegue", sender: self)
}
```

also please check whether these values are nil or not

```
let lastreservation = detail.value(forKey: "Reservation") as? String
let lasttake = detail.value(forKey: "Take") as? String
```

Comment: Both values are non-nil.

Comment: What about the values reservation,take in controller FoodDetail01

Comment: Strings - Either "Yes" or "No" are the expected responses. These values have been filled out in the CloudKit dashboard.

Comment: if let destination = segue.destination as? FoodDetail01
      {
        destination.reservation = lastreservation
        destination.take = lasttake
      } check whether these lines are executed or not

Comment: Your code was the most thorough, the addition of the button code was also appreciated. However, an unforeseen dilemma. When I click the button, the FoodDetail01 controller comes up, but unexpectedly, the same screen comes up again. In other words, I have two controllers of the same controller. Any ideas?

Comment: Which is the class of first view controller ??

Comment: The first view controller is FoodDetail

Comment: Check if there any segue from button to same view controller

Comment: If you are using the above code, don't set segue from button to viewController2. Set segue from viewController1 to viewConroller2

Comment: Question in that case. How would I set the segue from VC1 to VC2 without using the button. Does the code just work like that?

Comment: In the button click event you can invoke segue

Comment: @IBAction func booton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "lastsegue", sender: self)
}

Comment: Does that mean I do not require a physical link between VC1 and VC2 in the storyboard?

Comment: Ahh, had to delete an extra connection to the button via the storyboard connections windows.

Comment: You should have a physical link between VC1 and VC2. Not between button and VC2

Comment: Thats it Buddy :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have added `prepareForSegue` inside of your `booton` action but it is should be with your other class level methods.

```
@IBAction func booton(_ sender: Any) {
     //Button action code
}

//prepareForSegue is outside from that method like other method of class
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "lastsegue"
    {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? FoodDetail01 {
            let lastreservation = detail.value(forKey: "Reservation") as? String
            let lasttake = detail.value(forKey: "Take") as? String

            destination.reservation = lastreservation
            destination.take = lasttake
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**Note:** In Swift it is batter if you use native `Dictionary` with `subscript` instead of `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code for passing string value in segue.
Add ! after lastreservation and lasttake. If you not adding then it it passing nil value. you can check by adding break point.

```
@IBAction func booton(_ sender: Any) {
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "lastsegue"
    {
      if let destination = segue.destination as? FoodDetail01
      {
        let lastreservation = detail.value(forKey: "Reservation") as? String
        let lasttake = detail.value(forKey: "Take") as? String

        destination.reservation = lastreservation!
        destination.take = lasttake!
    }...
```